# How to use PC internet on Android mobile via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, internet, reverse-tether

How to use my PC internet on Android mobile via Bluetooth. I'm having a bluetooth dongle connected to my PC. My phone and the PC are paired.

**DETAILS**

- OS: Windows XP
- INTERNET CONNECTION MECHANISM : ADSL modem (connected to PC via
  Ethernet cable)
- Phone: Sony Xperia (Android Ice Cream Sandwitch)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First switch on your PC's and your phone's Bluetooth.
Make sure that your phone is paired up in your PC.
Goto **`"System Preferences"`**
In that goto **`"Sharing"`**
Then goto **`"Internet Sharing"`**
Now Select **`"USB Dongle"`** as the source
Now **`"Airport Wireless"`** as share via
And now you can connect your phone to the internet.

Comment: It should be noted that this is for Mac..

Comment: is there a way to do same using a `PC` instead of `Mac`